# R : Error writing empty dataframe using write.xlsx2

Tags: r, dataframe

I want to create an empty worksheet with colnames (from my empty dataframe), when that dataframe is empty. I get the following error when i try to export the dataframe:

> "java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 1" error while writing empty dataframe to xlsx using write.xlsx2 function.
>
> dup_target has two columns with zero rows.

Here is my code:

```
write.xlsx2(x = dup_target, file = "Client_Comparison.xlsx",
        sheetName = "Duplicates_Target", row.names = FALSE,append=TRUE)
```

Comment: Add a single element to each data frame vector containing only a space?  Or set the column headers individually using setCellValue, or add a vecor/list to the workbook containing the headers

Comment: Dinesh, I tried to edit this to put it in a more acceptable format, if I've changed the sense, please let me know